# Lightning URL Hacking Not Working when trying to prepopulate Lookup Fields

Tags: lightning-experience, urlhacking

I have created a new URL button on Opportunity Detail Page.
This button is creating new Quote. When I click on this button, two Lookup fields values should prepopulated (Opportuity, Account) on Quote. Below is what I tried but it is not working at all

```
/lightning/o/SBQQ__Quote__c/new?defaultFieldValues=SBQQ__Account__c={!Opportunity.AccountId},SBQQ__Opportunity2__c={!Opportunity.Id}
```

`SBQQ__Account__c` and `SBQQ__Opportunity2__c` these are the lookup field on quote.

Can someone please help me what's wrong in this URL

Comment: What behavior do you see when you say: it is not working at all

Comment: URL is opening New Quote page, but Account and Opportunity Fields are not populated

Comment: What does the URL look like when you get directed to the page? Does it still contain the Ids and fields? I essentially copied your example and used it on Opportunities (and standard Quote object & opp/acc lookup fields) and it worked fine. May try to just do one field at a time to debug (first just default opp, then default only acc, then default both opp & acc).

Comment: I tried with standard Quote object and it is working for that but not for SteelBrick Quote(CPQ).
Not even for one field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is fixed now
I was missing `nooverride=true` in the URL

```
/lightning/o/SBQQ__Quote__c/new?nooverride=true&defaultFieldValues=SBQQ__Account__c={!Opportunity.AccountId},SBQQ__Opportunity2__c={!Opportunity.Id}&recordTypeId=RECORDTYPEID
```

Comment: be aware that passing [recordTypeId to defaultFieldValues is not supported](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.links_useful_custom_buttons_create_record_dfv.htm&type=5) so you may see unexpected results.

Comment: I did test this by passing RecordTypeId and it was working for me as expected