# Custom button URL with default values to create a Lead from a Contact

Tags: lightning-experience, custom-button, list-button

I have created a custom URL button with default values to create a Lead from a Contact. I'm unable to map Lastname and email field values from contact to Lead.

Can anyone help with this?

```
lightning/o/Lead/new?recordTypeId=0125i0000000ZL6AAM&defaultFieldValues=
FirstName={!Contact.FirstName},
MiddleName={!Contact.MiddleName}
LastName ={!Contact.LastName},
Email ={!Contact.Email},
MobilePhone={!Contact.MobilePhone}
```

I tried this too

```
LastName ={!URLENCODE(Contact.LastName)},
Email ={!URLENCODE(Contact.Email)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding *nooverride=true* to the URL for me I am able to populate LastName and Email fields on Lead.

```
/lightning/o/Lead/new?nooverride=true&defaultFieldValues=
FirstName={!Contact.FirstName},
Email ={!Contact.Email},
MobilePhone={!Contact.MobilePhone},
LastName={!Contact.LastName},
Email={!Contact.Email}
```

As per Salesforce [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.links_useful_custom_buttons_create_record_dfv.htm&type=5) recordtypeId is not yet supported but it seems it is working as per this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/372712/lightning-url-hacking-not-working-when-trying-to-prepopulate-lookup-fields).

> NOTE Passing the RecordTypeId to defaultFieldValues isn’t yet
> supported. The recordTypeId influences routing behavior, layout
> assignment, and page assignment, so you can see unexpected results if
> you try to use it.